# Why I can't initialize a Mongo in Servlet

Tags: java, mongodb, servlets, mongo-java

I'm making java web project , and try to use mongodb.
but I found a problem,

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017)
```

when I use it in a main method, it is ok.
but when I use it in Servlet init() or doGet, doPost
it throws exceptions, it is like:

```
    Allocate exception for servlet RegServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.MongoException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2011-5-19 20:44:39 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you have not included a jar containing class `com.mongodb.MongoException` (hence why you're having `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`). There are no jars that is needed by your application to run MongoDB. Add the relevant Mongo jars in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder or your webapp server/container `lib` folder.

Comment: ok, thank you very much,^_^ but can you tell me whats the difference between copy to /lib and "use add external jar" method. why could that happen?

Comment: Web application containers use a specific class loading hierarchy, while the **use external jar** method in Eclipse doesn't. When you run it from the `main` method in Eclipse then an appropriate classpath is created by Eclipse. When you run it from a servlet the servlet classloader does not use any of Eclipse's build/run class path settings. You need to add it to WEB-INF/lib, and you can read up on classpath structures at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html .

Comment: Adding external jars only points to a jar whereas copying the jar to the lib means that your project/application has the jar in it entirely. Deploying your application which points to an external jars never copies the jar to the project and thus, it loses jar reference, whereas jars inside the lib are loaded by the classloader or web container to be used by your web application. I hope I explained as clearly as possible. :)

Comment: Got it, Thank you vert much for U guys' help :P